# Add background color to each element in *ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

Want to add a background colour to the row based on some condition. So I calculated colour code in a model element and want to set it in ngFor* element.

```
     <tr *ngFor="let plan of signalRService.bradcastedData;let ind = index" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': {{plan.RowBackgroundColorCode}}">
```

But it is not working.
I am sure.. there is a better to but can't find any yet.

Comment: Templates are for strings, not for objects - `[ngStyle]="{'background-color': plan.RowBackgroundColorCode}"`

Comment: @JakeHolzinger 

unfortunately not working..
Tried 
[ngStyle]="{'background-color': plan.RowBackgroundColorCode}"   which has value Hex color code
[ngStyle]="{'background-color': plan.RowBackgroundColor}" which has value red, blue 
not working. No bg color at all
Tried to carry boolean value and set the color based on that 
  [ngStyle]="{'background-color': (plan.HasAllocated)? 'blue':'red'}
  but always getting the setting red. 
          
    But I set the statci color ( below) then it works which is no use in my case
[ngStyle]="{'background-color': 'blue'}

Comment: Can you please add an example data so we can have a look on how are you storing the `RowBackgroundColorCode` property ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <tr *ngFor="let plan of signalRService.bradcastedData;let ind = index" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': plan.RowBackgroundColorCode">
```

Comment: unfortunately not working..
Tried 
[ngStyle]="{'background-color': plan.RowBackgroundColorCode}"   which has value Hex color code
[ngStyle]="{'background-color': plan.RowBackgroundColor}" which has value red, blue 
not working. No bg color at all
Tried to carry boolean value and set the color based on that 
  [ngStyle]="{'background-color': (plan.HasAllocated)? 'blue':'red'}
  but always getting the setting red. 
          
    But I set the statci color ( below) then it works which is no use in my case
[ngStyle]="{'background-color': 'blue'}

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.